# Given some zeroes of a real polynomial of a given degree, how can one find the remaining zeroes?

Tags: polynomials, roots

Here is what the problem says:

> If $2$, $-\sqrt{5}$, and $3+i$ are three zeroes of a $5$th degree polynomial function with real coefficients, find the other zeroes of multiplicity $1$.

I don't think I can use synthetic division because the function is not given. I honestly have no idea how else to solve it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If I have not been clear enough or you need more detail, or I am doing something wrong by asking this question, please let me know and I will fix it ASAP. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you know anything about how the zeroes of a real polynomial are related? For example, if you have a quadratic polynomial with two complex root, what is the relation between these two roots?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_root_theorem

Comment: Do you have real coefficients or rational coefficients?  If you have rational coefficients, then you can find all the roots, but if your coefficients are only real, then you might not have enough information.

Comment: Michael, the problem says only that it's a 5th degree polynomial with real coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a polynomial $p(x)=a_nx^n+...+a_1x+a_0$ has real coefficients and $r$ is a root, then $$0=\overline{0}=\overline{p(r)}=a_n\overline{r}^n+...+a_1\overline{r}+a_0$$

This means that if $r$ is a root then $\overline{r}$ is also a root.

Since $3+i$ is a root, then $3-i$ is also a root. Therefore

$$(x-2)(x+\sqrt{5})(x-3-i)(x-3+i)$$ divides our polynomial. Therefore the polynomial is any degree-5 polynomial divisible the this.

If we knew that the coefficients were rational. Then the polynomial would have to be divisible by the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{5}$. This is $(x-\sqrt{5})(x+\sqrt{5})$.

This would tell us that $$(x-2)(x+\sqrt{5})(x+\sqrt{5})(x-3-i)(x-3+i)$$ divides our polynomial. Therefore this is, up to a multiplicative constant, our degree-5 polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

This is not enough information to determine the polynomial or the remaining zeroes of multiplicity $1$. Per Lab's comment, the nonreal roots of a real polynomial come in complex conjugate pairs; since the quintic polynomial $p$ at hand is real and $3 + i$ is a root, so is $3 - i$. Thus, the polynomial is a multiple of
$$q(x) = (x - 2)(x + \sqrt{5})(x - (3 + i))(x - (3 - i)) = (x - 2)(x + \sqrt{5})(x^2 - 6 x + 10).$$
On the other hand, any of the quintic polynomials
$$p(x) = A (x - b) q(x)$$
satisfies the given root conditions, so we can only say (1) that $3 - i$ is another root of $q$ (unless $A = 0$, so that $p = 0$, it must be a single root; if it were not, $3 + i$ would be a multiple root, but counting shows that this would imply that $\deg p > 5$), and (2) $b$ will be a single root iff it is not $2, -\sqrt{5}$.

Now, if we knew that $p$ was rational, since $-\sqrt{5}$ is not rational, $p$ would have as a factor the minimal polynomial of $-\sqrt{5}$, namely $x^2 - 5$. This would force the remaining factor to be $x - r$, where $r$ is the other real root of this minimal polynomial, namely $\sqrt{5}$ (which is hence a single root) and determine $p$ (up to an overall nonzero constant):
$$p(x) = A (x - 2) (x^2 - 5) (x^2 - 6 x + 10).$$

Comment: A fifth degree polynomial will have 5 roots (not necessarily distinct).  You are given three and need to find the other 2.  One of the roots, 3+ i, is non-real, and the coefficients are real so another root must be 3- i.  One of the roots, $-\sqrt{5}$ is real but irrational so **if you are requiring that the coefficients be rational (equivalently integer)** then the final root must be $\sqrt{5}$.  But without that condition, the fifth root could be anything.  For example, $x^5- (8+ \sqrt{5})x^4+ (21+ 8\sqrt{5})x^3- (10+ 2\sqrt{5})x+ 10\sqrt{5}$ has roots 2, 3- i, 3+ i, $\sqrt{5}$, and 0.

Comment: I'm not sure what the purpose of this comment is, as everything it says is already mentioned in the answer.